# jQuery: Setting attribute required for input tag

Tags: jquery, input, attributes, required

I was trying to set attribute to an input tag using jQuery. All other attributes for input tag like maxlength,name,class worked well. But i'm having trouble with required attribute.

I tried this way

```
 $("<label><strong>Class"+fare+"</strong></label><input type='text' value='' />")
.attr("class", "nameval") .attr("name", "class"+fare+"") .attr("required","required")
```

I also tried other ways refering to some forums

```
.attr("required","")
.attr("required",true)
.attr("required","true")
.prop("required",true)
```

Please let me know where i was wrong.

Comment: What are you trying to do with that HTML string? Appending it to the DOM? Using it as a selector?

Comment: i am having a button onclicking it would add input fields to the form @Alvaro and i'm also trying to validate those fields. So i'm using that varable fare in order to dynamically give names for the input elements.

Comment: .attr("required","required") works fine in my test.

Comment: @sudhAnsu63 is there any problem with other code i'm using

Comment: .attr("required","")  //clears this attribute
.attr("required",true) // sets required
.attr("required","true")  //sets required
.attr("required", "required") //sets required

Comment: @sudhAnsu63 i have tried every possibel thing and tested but still nothing changed. I'm unable to validate that way.May be i think there's a problem with other code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to append that HTML, then, why you are using it as a selector?

Just create it directly in the string:

```
$(form).append("<label><strong>Class"+fare+"</strong></label><input type='text' value='' required='required"/>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this.

```
var element = $("<label><strong>Class"+fare+"</strong></label><input type='text' value='' />")
.attr("class", "nameval") .attr("name", "class"+fare+"") .attr("required","required");

$("#MyFormId").append(element);
```